# Loading ruby-serialized data in Java for indexing rubygems

Tags: java, ruby, rubygems, marshalling, artifactory

Is there a way to read the ruby-Marshalled data in Java.
I need to read the gzipped Marshalled latest_specs.4.8.gz file of rubygems in Java for my use case.

What I have noticed is that Ruby uses the Marshalled format of Version 4.8 where as Java is using the version 5(STREAM_VERSION in ObjectStreamConstants) and I think this is giving an exception "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 04085B02" in my code.

I tried with jruby but getting an exception "undefined class/module Gem::Version"

I hope this is what is done in artifactory for indexing the gems.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Marshal format is documented. If you want to read it in Java, you will have to write a decoder for it. But, the Marshal file may contain Ruby objects which expect their respective classes to be in memory, so you will also have to implement a Java version of those classes.

Or, you could just a language-independent serialization format such as JSON, YAML, XML, ASN.1, BSON, BER, BERT, ogdl, …

Comment: Yeah when I am trying to write a decoder for it in Java I am getting the above exception. I want to read and generate the index of rubygems just like how rubygems/geminabox does. For that I need to be able to read the index file that is already generated which is latest_specs.4.8. Once I am able to read the file I can map the respective objects to Java equivalents.

Comment: As this file is generated externally I cannot change the format.